# Change css of selected ListView row

Tags: asp.net, css

I want to know how to apply css on any particular row of ListView. Is there any property of  ListView?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can create a SelectedItemTemplate and give it whatever style you want:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.selecteditemtemplate.aspx